# Simple JQuery accordion slideshow issues and Firefox browser list issues

Tags: jquery, accordion, slideshow

I am having a strange problem with a simple accordion slideshow that I created.  The goal is to have it automatically scroll infinitely every 5 seconds and then restart the timer whenever a specific picture is clicked.  It seems to work just fine, It will scroll indefinitely and clicking on a picture switches to the correct picture.  However, when I click on a picture and the timer restarts it seems to stop looping back to the first picture after reaching the last item and gets stuck there.  I hope this is not confusing.  Basically, everything works until it reaches the end of the list after having any list item clicked.

One other problem that I am having is that the pictures do not appear in the Firefox browser, just the alt text in list style.  I cannot figure out what needs to be different in my CSS for the Firefox browser.

Thank you!

Here is the Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

activeItem = $("#slideshow li:first");
$(activeItem).addClass('active');

timeoutID = setTimeout(autoscroll, 5000);

function autoscroll(){
if($(activeItem).is("#slideshow li:last")){next = $("#slideshow li:first");}    
else{next = $(activeItem).next("#slideshow li");}
$(activeItem).animate({width: "75px"}, {duration:300, queue:false});
$(next).animate({width: "850px"}, {duration:300, queue:false});
activeItem = next;
timeoutID = setTimeout(autoscroll, 5000);}

$("#slideshow li").click(function(){
clearTimeout(timeoutID);
$(activeItem).animate({width: "75px"}, {duration:300, queue:false});
$(this).animate({width: "850px"}, {duration:300, queue:false});
activeItem = this;
timeoutID = setTimeout(autoscroll, 5000);
});

});</script>
```

The CSS that goes with it:

```
#container{
width: 1100px;
margin: auto;
border: 1px solid black;}

#slideshow{
list-style: none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
height: 400px;}

#slideshow li{
float: left;
display: block;
height: 400px;
width: 75px;
padding: 15px 0;
overflow: hidden;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 1.5em;
border-left: 1px solid #fff;}

#slideshow li img {
border: none;
border-right: 1px solid #fff;
float: left;
margin: -15px 15px 0 0;}

#slideshow li.active {
width: 850px;}
```

And the HTML is just a simple list (the images are localized):

```
<div id="container"> 
 <ul id="slideshow">
  <li><a><img src="C:\Users\Scott\Google Drive\Website\Bella Bri.jpg" alt="boat"></a>   </li>
  <li><a><img src="C:\Users\Scott\Google Drive\Website\DREAMHACK-UCOS.jpg" alt="comp"></a></li>
  <li><a><img src="C:\Users\Scott\Google Drive\Website\manda-bay-lamu.jpg" alt="beach"></a></li>
  <li><a><img src="C:\Users\Scott\Google Drive\Website\car-picture.jpg" alt="car"></a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```